# Is $3x^2+7$ uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$?

Tags: functions, uniform-continuity

Is $3x^2+7$ uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$?

My argument: Yes, Since $3x^2+7$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ is compact, any continuous function on compact set is uniformly continuous. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct. $\,\,$

Comment: That is correct assuming you already have the theorem you state.  Often a question like this would be posed before proving that theorem and you are expected to go back to the definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is indeed a direct consequence of the [Heine Cantor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) theorem.